# How to extend the primary partition for Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I consistently run out of space on root / . Server has a SSD and a 3.7TB HDD . I am looking to extend the root partition which is only 4GB in size. SSD has some unutilized space. I am also looking to move the /var folder to the 3.7TB HDD. Have been reading around but have struggled to find a safe method. Here is the fdisk -l output in rescue mode.

```
rescue:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 640 MiB, 671088640 bytes, 1310720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 3999677808640 bytes, 7811870720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt


Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7811870686 7811868639  3.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sda: 223.4 GiB, 239903703040 bytes, 468561920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x46e61c3e

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048   8390655   8388608     4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        8390656  12584959   4194304     2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       12584960 468561919 455976960 217.4G 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/devloc64ssd-usr: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/devloc64ssd-var: 55 GiB, 59055800320 bytes, 115343360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/devloc64ssd-home: 94.4 GiB, 101317607424 bytes, 197885952 secto                                                                                        rs
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/devloc64ssd-opt: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: For future reference, please use the code sample formatting tool `{}` around shell commands and their output or scripts. This'll keep the original formatting and ensure readability.

Answer (score 0):

With the current partitioning scheme on your disk, your options are fairly limited for the root partition. You could sacrifice the swap partition and extend the root partition, or temporarily disable swap and create a new swap partition on a LVM logical volume. However, beyond the 6GB in non-LVM space you're looking at some serious downtime, and it might even be faster to just reinstall the server.

For this:

- Disable swap (`swapoff`)
- Delete `/dev/sda2` and it's entry in `/etc/fstab`
- Extend `/dev/sda1` with fdisk
- Grow the filesystem (`resize2fs`)

Depending on the RAM your server is using, you might not even need a swap partition, but in case you do want it, create a new LVM logical volume and point `/etc/fstab` to it.

With regards to `/var`, that should be fairly simple. Boot the system in single user mode, create a new LVM volume, copy all the files to the new filesystem and change the entries in `/etc/fstab` to point to the new volume. Don't delete the files from the original filesystem but test it first. If everything works as expected, reboot again in single user mode, umount `/var` and then delete the files on the root filesystem and reboot.